# Javascript / XPath error

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey

I was experimenting around with XPath, basically I'm trying to load a HTML page using XMLHttpRequest and select an element inside it from its XPath.

Here's my code (Greasemonkey/Js):

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
method: 'GET',
url: url,
headers: {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible) Greasemonkey',
    'Accept': 'application/atom+xml,application/xml,text/xml',
},
onload: function(responseDetails)
{
    var rs = document.evaluate("/html/body/div",responseDetails.responseText,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    var n = rs.snapshotItem(0);
    alert(n.innerHTML);
}});
```

But it isn't working.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 1
[nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" 
location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Admin/Application%20Data
/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/mq3w8kw4.default/extensions/%7Be4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-
b12d-ee082ba24781%7D/components/greasemonkey.js :: anonymous :: line 587" data: no]
```

Comment: “it isn't working” is not a very helpful message. What's the result you get? An error message? Does the XMLHttpRequest fail? Is `onload` never called?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. This is the error I'm getting: 

uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 1 [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Admin/Application%20Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/mq3w8kw4.default/extensions/%7Be4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781%7D/components/greasemonkey.js :: anonymous :: line 587" data: no]

Comment: when adding to a post, please edit the post and add the extra info there instead of appending a comment.  I took care of it for you this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run an XPath query on a string, `responseText`, try `responseXML` instead.

Still, I'm guessing that unless the web page you are loading has completely valid XHTML, this too will fail. If you want to run XPath queries on mangled HTML, try loading loading it in an iframe, then use `iframe.contentDocument.evaluate`

Comment: yah, responseXML doesn't work, I guess the page isn't valid. I don't like the idea of using an iframe. Maybe regexp might be a better way of extracting the value I need w/o using xpath. Thanks for you answer.